# Iterating through array of structs based on json causes preview to fail

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

The code takes json data from list.json and I created a swift view BookView as another file.

```
import SwiftUI

struct product: Codable, Hashable {
    var name: String
    var author: String
    var page: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    func jsonTwo() -> [product]{
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "list", withExtension: "json")!
            let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let products = try? decoder.decode([product].self, from: data)
            return products!
        }
    
    @State var number: Int = 5
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    ForEach(jsonTwo(), id: \.self) {item in
                        BookView(name: "item.name",author: "item.author",page: "item.page")
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Books")
                Button(action: {
                    // Button tapped
                }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.rectangle")
                            .font(Font.system(.largeTitle).bold())
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    })
                        .padding(.top)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This code give me the error "Cannot preview in this file -- Failed to update preview" but the following code works fine (difference in the ForEach statement) .Note I put the parameters for BookView in quotes to test.

```
import SwiftUI

struct product: Codable, Hashable {
    var name: String
    var author: String
    var page: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    func jsonTwo() -> [product]{
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "list", withExtension: "json")!
            let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let products = try? decoder.decode([product].self, from: data)
            return products!
        }
    
    @State var number: Int = 5
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    ForEach(0..<number) {item in
                        BookView(name: "item.name",author: "item.author",page: "item.page")
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Books")
                Button(action: {
                    // Button tapped
                }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.rectangle")
                            .font(Font.system(.largeTitle).bold())
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    })
                        .padding(.top)
            }
        }
    }

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .previewDevice("iPhone 11")
    }
}
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the first one doesn't work, the second one does.

Comment: Does it work if you run it in the simulator?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson no it does not, the app opens to a black screen and stays like that.

Comment: Then most likely it crashes when you start it, maybe it can't find or decode the json file. Check the console in Xcode and/or run it in the debugger.

Comment: RemoteHumanReadableError: Failed to update preview.

Error encountered when sending 'previewInstances' message to agent. The preview process appears to have crashed. This it the error I get when I open the diagnostics @JoakimDanielson

Comment: I meant any error when running the app, like I said use the debugger or add some print statements and check the console (Cmd+Shift+C) when running the app.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'm new to iOS programming but where would I add a print statement. I think there is an error with the function as the preview doesn't render when I call it. Where should I put a print statement to test the function?